# The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context

Tags: sql-server, sspi

I have a small home network of pc's all running Windows 10. None of the PC's have been or are in a domain. One (an intel NUC) runs Sql Server and my Surface 3 has Visual Studio. I use my Microsoft login for both. This setup has been running fine for almost 2 years. 
Now I suddenly get the above error when trying to connect using integrated security.

Sql Authentication works fine.
I can also remote into the NUC and run SSMS without a problem.
I have followed the troubleshooting guide without success (KB 811889) 
NTLM seems to be operating OK on the NUC.
I pinged -a IPAddress and it resolved correctly to the name of the NUC 
SQL Server uses NT Service\MSSQLSERVER. I tried using LocalSystem but still didn't work

All the help articles I have found assume there is a domain or suggest Sql Authentication as a solution.

Only recent change has been installing Windows Update for Windows 10 Version 1607 on the NUC

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you paste entire error message along with error message in eventvwr,,also look at this blog and try to apply resolution

Comment: In our case,our accounts are all domain joined,we created SPNs for them and we never faced the issue

Comment: Domains would be overkill. I am the only user. Error message is as above. Inner exception is nothing

Comment: Did you recently change the account SQL service was running under from something else to NT Service\MSSQLSERVER?